# how to add two large unsigned integer in c

Tags: c

so I'm actually trying to do this exercise;

input two **integer** number, with a >= 1 and b <= 2 power of 32. find the value of a + b

I know this is a simple task but the things is, for small numbers value it worked correctly ( like 20 + 9 = 29), but for value like 1788909566 + 2626399043 the result is incorrect (it should be 4415308609 but 120341313 came out)

this the code that I worked on :

```
int main() {
  unsigned int a, b;

  scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);

  printf("%u + %u = %u", a, b, a + b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perform the sum by first casting the input variables to 'unsigned long', which is a 64-bit type (as opposed to unsigned int, which is 32 bits)

Comment: `unsigned long` does not have to be 64 bits and `unsigned int` does not have to be 32 bits

Comment: 4415308609 is too large to be stored in a 32-bit unsigned int

Comment: Given "... b <= 2 power of 32.", an `unsigned` is too small to store `pow(2,32)`.  Use `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `long long` data type while dealing with large numbers."`%llu`" is the format specifier for long long.
unsigned long long is of **8 bytes** and stores number in range of **0** to **18,446,744,073,709,551,615**

```
int main() {
      unsigned long long a, b;
      scanf("%llu %llu" , &a, &b);
      printf("%llu + %llu = %llu", a, b, a + b);
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

because the result wrapped around.
You need to store the result in the larger integer type, or cast to the larger integer type. You need also to use the correct `printf` format to print `unsigned long long` number.

```
int main() {
  unsigned int a, b;

  scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);

  printf("%u + %u = %llu", a, b, (unsigned long long)a + b);

  return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {
  unsigned int a, b;
  unsigned long long c;;

  scanf("%u %u", &a, &b);
  c = (unsigned long long)a + b;

  printf("%u + %u = %llu\n", a, b, c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou it worked ! but can i ask why is it different with declaring a new variable "unsigned long long c = a + b" ?

Comment: it is not differnt

Comment: i've tried this before (declaring a new unsigned long long variable), but the result yield 120341313,which is wrong

Comment: @imnotarobot: in your example, ```a + b``` is performed with their old types before the result is promoted to a larger type, so the wraparound still happens. That's why you have to cast one of them to a larger type before addiing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel :) indeed